# Can someone help me put my brain to rest "C Language"

Tags: c

Ok this is a simple C code but for some unknown reason the program refuse to compile and give segmentation fault 11 Please help me

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct {
    int P_answer[9];
    int number;
} BOX;

int main()
{
    BOX Matrix[8][8];
    int i,j;
    int k;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            Matrix[i][j].number=0;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[0]=1;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[1]=2;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[2]=3;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[3]=4;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[4]=5;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[5]=6;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[6]=7;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[7]=8;
            Matrix[i][j].P_answer[8]=9;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `refuse to compile` or `give segmentation fault`?

Answer (score 15):

Matrix is an 8-by-8 array; each of your loops goes through 9 iterations.

Answer (score 4):

The indexes of an array go from 0 to (size-1).

In your for-loops you go from 0 to size.

That's the reason of your segmentation fault.